# Python retry with dynamic parameters

Tags: python, retrying, tenacity

Tried this in the [retrying](https://pypi.org/project/retrying/) and [tenacity](https://pypi.org/project/tenacity/) python libraries to no avail.

Retries are typically used with a decorator, for example as shown in metacode below:

```
class FooBar:

   @retry(attempts=3)
   def dosomething():
      ...
```

I want the retry parameters to be configurable on the class

```
class FooBar:
   def __init__(retries=0):
       self.retries = retries

   @retry(attempts=self.retries)
   def dosomething():
      ...
```

Obviously this will break because the decorator cannot accedss object attributes (ie. cannot access `self`).  So figured this would work:

```
def dosomething():
   with retry(attempts=self.retries):
       ...
```

But neither library allows for retry to be called in a `with` block

```
>  with retry():
E  AttributeError: __enter__
```

**What is the preferred way to wrap retry logic with dynamic parameters?**

Comment: May I ask... What is tenacity? This is the only question with it, so I presume you have created it.

Comment: I have not created tenacity - it is a fork of the `retrying` library in python which apparently has no longer been in devleopment since 2016 and had bugs.  I've seen `tenacity` and `backoff` listed as alternatives in related threads.  I created the tag just now since its been mentioned in a few different threads at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needn't use deorators with the `@` syntax - they can also be used as functions.

```
from tenacity import retry, stop_after_attempt

class CustomClass:
    def __init__(self, retries):
        decorator = retry(stop=stop_after_attempt(retries), reraise=True)
        self.method_with_retry = decorator(self.method)
    
    def method(self, x):
        print('Trying...')
        if x % 2:
            raise ValueError
        return x

CustomClass(3).method_with_retry(11)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested function can help this:

```py
class FooBar:
   def __init__(retries=0):
       self.retries = retries

   def dosomething():
       @retry(attempts=self.retries)
       def _dosomething():
          ...
       return _dosomething()
```